# How to add custom table in liferay 7 elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

I have added a custom table with data in liferay. Now i want to search those data in elastic search.What will be the approach to get the data.
Suppose I add a custom table add entity in service.xml then i want to search these data from elastic search url sample http://localhost:9200.

```
<entity local-service="true" name="Student" remote-service="true"
        uuid="true">
        <column name="studentId" primary="true" type="long" />

        <column name="name" type="String" />
        <column name="sollNumber" type="int" />
        <column name="entryDate" type="Date" />
        <order by="asc">
            <order-column name="name" />
        </order>
        <finder name="Name" return-type="Collection">
            <finder-column name="name" />
        </finder>
    </entity>
```

I have added data from mysql script and get those data through elatic search url

Answer (score 0):

You could [make your entity an Asset](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/adding-updating-and-deleting-assets-for-custom-entities). Liferay uses Indexers for maintaining the external index data (and you'd have to write one). Alternatively (if you don't care about your data being found in Liferay, and shown in Liferay's search results, you could also index to Elasticsearch manually whenever your data changes (e.g. on every `add...`, `update...` or `delete...` method call)